# How to trace COM/ActiveX dependencies?

Tags: debugging, activex, dependencies

Is there anything "out there", similar to Dependency Walker, which walks and reports the dependencies of an ActiveX/COM object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two useful tools you can try:

[Depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Comment: Okay, depends I know about already. In fact, it's what I referred to earlier as "Dependency Walker" and its not all that useful in this situation because it only walks the standard DLL dependencies, not the COM DLL ones. 

I'm not as familiar with Process Explorer. Will check that out as soon as ...